# How To Store Data in Sql with UTC TimeZone when the system local in somwhere else

Tags: sql, timezone, local, utc

i know there is not any way to change timezone of an application globaly,
 but is there any way to store datetimes in utc on sqlserver.
right now any time  i submit to server considerd as local. i can change that by `ConvertToUTC()` method in .net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Think easiest way is to use a function inside my application to fix time zone for me then send data to/From Server. I used 2 different functions :

```
 Friend tZone As TimeZoneInfo

 Public Function TimeZone_Get(ByVal time As DateTime, ByVal Tolocal As Boolean) As DateTime
    Dim t As DateTime = time

    If Tolocal = True Then
        t = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(time, tZone)
    End If
    Return t
End Function

Public Function TimeZone_Set(ByVal time As DateTime, ByVal Islocal As Boolean) As DateTime
    Dim t As DateTime = time
    If Islocal = True Then
        t = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(time, tZone)
    End If
    Return t
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using the SQL function:

```
getUTCdate();
```

See here for more info: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178635.aspx

Note the UTC datetime is derived from the Operating System of which the SQL Server is running.